# Facing a problem with the lookup in the second (student) table that matches all incoming output records mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm facing a problem with the lookup in the second (student) table that matches all incoming output records of the first(test) table. I have two collections "tests" and "students". "Test" collection contains all school tests and the "student" table contains student's attended tests. Student table contains "pastTest"(test attended in past with status "pass" or "fail")array. I want to retrieve student who passed all incoming tests (we retrieve from the tests table)

test table: _id (primary ket)
student.pastTests.testId (need to match with test._id)

**Test Document:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
    "testDate" : {
        "term" : 1,
        "week" : 7
    },
    "retestDate" : {
        "term" : 1,
        "week" : 10
    },
    "testOrder" : "1.1",
    "testDateScheduled" : true,
    "retestDateScheduled" : true
}
```

**Student Document:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c92dd994e8e6b2c1647d0d0"),
    "completedYears" : [],
    "firstName" : "Andrew",
    "lastName" : "Jonhson",
    "teacherId" : ObjectId("5bf36b1076696374e65feb4f"),
    "yearGroup" : "0",
    "schoolId" : 40001,
    "currentTest" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
    "pastTests" : [ 
        {
           
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d3570645045863d373f6db1"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
            "status" : "pass"
        }, 
        {
           
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d425af07708f5636c3bec1c"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5fc460e39c2c58e44109"),
            "status" : "pass"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e54a875fab079f4d03570"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b6492bb581c2ceb553fef"),
            "status" : "fail"
        }, 
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-21T00:40:57.401Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-24T19:55:38.291Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "holdTests" : [],
    "completedTests" : [],
    "className" : "dd",
}
```

**Query:**

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
     {
       $match: {
           yearGroup: '-1',
            $or : [
                {
                   $and: [
                    {'retestDateScheduled': true},
                    { 'retestDate.term': { $lt: 4 } },
                   ]
                },
                {
                   $and: [
                    {'testDateScheduled': true},
                    { 'testDate.term': { $lt: 4 } },
                   ]
                }
            ]
       }
     },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'students',
        let: {testId: '$_id', schoolId: 49014, yearGroup: '-1'},
        pipeline: [
            
        ]
      }
    }
])
```

**Note:** Initial match query returns all tests of the term-1, now I have to retrieve students who passed in all tests of the term-1.

**Lookup stage is pending** - facing problem with lookup in second (student) table who match all incoming output records of first(test) collection

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
db.tests.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            // Your match condition
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            term_1_testIds: { $push: "$_id" },
            test_count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "students",
            let: { term_1_testIds: '$term_1_testIds', schoolId: 40001, totalTestCount: "$test_count" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$schoolId", "$$schoolId"] }
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$pastTests" },
                {
                    $match: {
                        "pastTests.status": "pass",
                        $expr: { $in: ["$pastTests.testId", "$$term_1_testIds"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$_id",
                        firstName: { $first: "$firstName" },
                        yearGroup: { $first: "$yearGroup" },
                        schoolId: { $first: "$schoolId" },
                        currentTest: { $first: "$currentTest" },
                        passedTestCount: { $sum: 1 },
                        pastTests: { $push: "$pastTests" }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$passedTestCount", "$$totalTestCount"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "students"
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : null,
    "term_1_testIds" : [
        ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
        ObjectId("5c9b5fc460e39c2c58e44109"),
        ObjectId("5c9b6492bb581c2ceb553fef")
    ],
    "test_count" : 3,
    "students" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c92dd994e8e6b2c1647d0d1"),
            "firstName" : "Dheemanth",
            "yearGroup" : "0",
            "schoolId" : 40001,
            "currentTest" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
            "passedTestCount" : 3,
            "pastTests" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3570645045863d373f6db1"),
                    "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
                    "status" : "pass"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d425af07708f5636c3bec1c"),
                    "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5fc460e39c2c58e44109"),
                    "status" : "pass"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e54a875fab079f4d03570"),
                    "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b6492bb581c2ceb553fef"),
                    "status" : "pass"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This how my `tests` collection looks like

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/27/2019, 5:24:58 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b6492bb581c2ceb553fef"),
    "name" : "Test 3"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/27/2019, 5:04:28 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b5fc460e39c2c58e44109"),
    "name" : "Test 2"
},

/* 3 createdAt:3/27/2019, 4:48:40 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
    "name" : "Test 1"
}
```

This is how my `students` collection looks like:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/21/2019, 6:10:57 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c92dd994e8e6b2c1647d0d1"),
    "firstName" : "Dheemanth",
    "yearGroup" : "0",
    "schoolId" : 40001,
    "currentTest" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
    "pastTests" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d3570645045863d373f6db1"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
            "status" : "pass"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d425af07708f5636c3bec1c"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5fc460e39c2c58e44109"),
            "status" : "pass"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e54a875fab079f4d03570"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b6492bb581c2ceb553fef"),
            "status" : "pass"
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/21/2019, 6:10:57 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c92dd994e8e6b2c1647d0d0"),
    "firstName" : "Andrew",
    "yearGroup" : "0",
    "schoolId" : 40001,
    "currentTest" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
    "pastTests" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d3570645045863d373f6db1"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5c1005729b2bf23f3290"),
            "status" : "pass"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d425af07708f5636c3bec1c"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b5fc460e39c2c58e44109"),
            "status" : "pass"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e54a875fab079f4d03570"),
            "testId" : ObjectId("5c9b6492bb581c2ceb553fef"),
            "status" : "fail"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also:
In your first `$match` stage, `$and` operator is redundant inside `$or` array it should be like this:

```js
{
    $match: {
        yearGroup: '-1',
        $or: [
            {
                'retestDateScheduled': true,
                'retestDate.term': { $lt: 4 }
            },
            {
                'testDateScheduled': true,
                'testDate.term': { $lt: 4 }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Will improve it using $facte in next edit if posible.

Comment: Thank you so much dheemanth bhat, It works well for me.

Comment: How can I merge pastTests array in the student record, it returns a single object of pastTests instead of array?

Comment: You just have to $push it to an array. Check the updated answer.